# How to implement BOT engine like WIT.AI for on an on-premise solution?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I want to build a chatbot for a customer service application. I tried SaaS services like Wit.Ai, Motion.Ai, Api.Ai, LUIS.ai etc. These cognitive services find the "**intent**" and "**entities**" when trained with the typical interactions model.

I need to build chatbot for **on-premise** solution, without using any of these SaaS services.

e.g Typical conversation would be as following -

```
    Can you book me a ticket?
    Is my ticket booked?
    What is the status of my booking BK02?
    I want to cancel the booking BK02.
    Book the tickets
```

StandFord NLP toolkit looks promising but there are licensing constraints. Hence I started experimenting with the OpenNLP. I assume, there are two OpenNLP tasks involved -

1. Use 'Document Categorizer' to find out the intent
2. Use 'Named Entity Recognition' to find out entities

Once the context is identified, I will call my application APIS to build the response.

- Is it a right approach?
- How good OpenNLP is in parsing the text?
- Can I use Facebook **FASTTEXT** library for Intent identification?
- Is there any other open source library which can be helpful in building the BOT?
- Will "**SyntaxNet**" be useful for my adventure?

I prefer to do this in Java. BUT open to node or python solution too.

PS - I am new to NLP.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? This is a common problem and as you said I'm not able to find a solution. Either businesses aren't concerned too much about the privacy of their customers or NLP is not there as media projects it. It would be great if you could share your Open NLP implementation details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this. It says it is an Open-source language understanding for bots and a drop-in replacement for popular NLP tools like wit.ai, api.ai or LUIS

https://rasa.ai/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my other answer for a plan of attack when using Luis.ai:

[Creating an API for LUIS.AI or using .JSON files in order to train the bot for non-technical users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990171/creating-an-api-for-luis-ai-or-using-json-files-in-order-to-train-the-bot-for-n/41125993#41125993)

In short use Luis.ai and setup some intents, start with one or two and train it based on your domain. I am using asp.net to call the Cognitive Service API as outlined above.  Then customize the response via some JQuery...you could search a list of your rules in a javascript array when each intent or action is raised by the response from Luis.

If your Bot is english based, then I would use OpenNLP's sentence parser to dump the customer input into a database (I do this today). I then use the OpenNLP tokenizer and push the keywords (less the stop words) and Parts of Speech into a database table for keyword analysis. I have a custom Sentiment model built for OpenNLP that will tag each sentence with a Pos, Neg, Neutral sentiment...You can then use this to identify negative customer service feedback.  To build your own Sentiment model have a look at SentiWord.net and download their domain agnostic data file to build and train an OpenNLP model or have a look at this Node version...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sentiword

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend Rasa, it's great for your use case, working on-premise easily, handling intents and entities for you and on top of that it has a friendly community too.

Check out my repo for an example of how to build a chatbot with Rasa that interacts with a simple database: https://github.com/nmstoker/lockebot

Answer (score 0):

I tried RASA, But one glitch I found there was the inability of Rasa to answer unmatched/untrained user texts.

Now, I'm using **ChatterBot** and I'm totally in love with it.

Use "ChatterBot", and host it locally using - 'flask-chatterbot-master"

Links:

**ChatterBot Installation:** https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html

**Host Locally using - flask-chatterbot-master**: https://github.com/chamkank/flask-chatterbot

Cheers,

Ratnakar

Comment: From review: Would you please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51896510/edit) and improve this answer with more details about ChatterBot? (e.g. explain why it is a good alternative). Also please avoid informality (e.g. Good luck!, Cheers, etc). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the RASA and Botkit framework we can build the onpremise chatbot and the NLP engine for any channel. Please follow this link for End to End steps on building the same. An awsome blog that helped me to create a one for my office

https://creospiders.blogspot.com/2018/03/complete-on-premise-and-fully.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all any chatbot is going to be the program that runs along with the NLP, Its the NLP that brings the knowledge to the chatbot. NLP lies on the hands of the Machine learning techniques.

There are few reasons why the on premise chatbots are less.

- We need to build the infrastructure
- We need to train the model often

But using the cloud based NLP may not provide the data privacy and security and also the flexibility of including my business logic is very less.

All together going to the on premise or on cloud is based on the needs and the use case of the requirements.

How ever please refer this link for end to end knowledge on building the chatbot on premise with very few steps and easily and fully customisable.

[Complete On-Premise and Fully Customisable Chat Bot - Part 1 - Overview](https://creospiders.blogspot.com/2018/03/complete-on-premise-and-fully.html)

[Complete On-Premise and Fully Customisable Chat Bot - Part 2 - Agent Building Using Botkit](https://creospiders.blogspot.com/2018/03/complete-on-premise-and-fully_16.html)

[Complete On-Premise and Fully Customisable Chat Bot - Part 3 - Communicating to the Agent that has been built](https://creospiders.blogspot.com/2018/04/CompleteOn-PremiseandFullyCustomisableChatBotpart3.html)

[Complete On-Premise and Fully Customisable Chat Bot - Part 4 - Integrating the Natural Language Processor NLP](https://creospiders.blogspot.com/2018/07/complete-on-premise-and-fully.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this package.*

Abodit NLP (https://nlp.abodit.com) can do what you want but it's .NET only at present.

In particular you can easily connect it to databases and can provide custom Tokens that are queries against a database. It's all strongly-typed and adding new rules is as easy as adding a method in C#.

It's also particularly adept at turning date time expressions into queries. For example "next month on a Thursday after 4pm" becomes `((((DatePart(year,[DATEFIELD])=2019) AND (DatePart(month,[DATEFIELD])=7)) AND (DatePart(dw,[DATEFIELD])=4)) AND DatePart(hour,[DATEFIELD])>=16)`